# OpenLayers freehanddraw forEachFeatureInExtent returns features not in shape

Tags: openlayers

I am not a newbie.
I am trying to get the features(icons) found inside a closed freehand line.
The approach I am taking is to take the extent returned from the drawing and
use it to get the features(icons) inside the drawing. This works. It includes some extra features(icons).  Is there a better approach to finding featues(icons) inside the freehand drawing that is more accurate? If not I have had some success using the following:

The extent returned with `draw.on('drawend',  function (event) {` 
is used to get features in closed line drawn on map.

`vectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent` will have features not inside drawing

```
var geomA = event.feature.getGeometry();

var bhpoints = geomA.flatCoordinates;
```

I use these `flatCoordinates(xy)` to compare to each feature to get a more
accurate decision whether the feature is in or outside of the closed line.

This works but will miss once and a while.

To restate my goal:

I want to find the features(icons) inside of a freehand drawing and the
obvious solution with extents needs better accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

If by 'closed freehand line' you mean freehand polygon you could check each point feature in the extent is inside the polygon geometry:

```
vectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent(geomA.getExtent(), function(feature) {
   if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point' && geomA.intersectsCoordinate(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()) {
      ....
      ....
   }
});
```